# Grouping by many columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I basically have a dataset that looks as follows

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Count
A      B     1      50
A      B     1      50
A      C     20     1
A      D     17     2
A      E     5      70
A      E     15     20
```

Suppose it is called data. I basically do `data.groupby(by=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'], as_index=False, sort=False).sum()`, which should give me this:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Count
A      B     1      100
A      C     20     1
A      D     17     2
A      E     5      70
A      E     15     20
```

However, this returns an empty dataset, which does have the columns I want but no rows. The only caveat is that the `by` parameter is getting calculated dynamically, instead of fixed (thats because the columns might change, although Count will always be there).

Any ideas on why this could be failing, and how to fix it?

EDIT: Further searching revealed that pandas' groupby removes rows that have NULL at any column. This is a problem for me because every single column might be NULL. Hence, the actual question is: any reasonable way to deal with NULLs and still use groupby?

Comment: Strange...I literally copied your data into a csv file, and ran the code and it gives me the output you're expecting. How are you dynamically generating the columns to group by? Thats the only difference I can see

Comment: Please see edit. It seems there is no official way to do this, people just replace the values with placeholders...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would love to be corrected here, but I'm not sure if there is a clean way to handle missing data. As you noted, Pandas will just exclude rows from groupby that contain NaN values

You could fill the NaN values with something beyond the range of your data:

```
data = pd.read_csv("c:/Users/simon/Desktop/data.csv")

data.fillna(-999, inplace=True)

new = data.groupby(by=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'], as_index=False, sort=False).sum()
```

Which is messy because it wont add those values to the correct group by for the summation. But theres no real way to groupby something thats missing

Another method might be to fill each column separately with some missing value that is appropriate for that variable.

Comment: That's what I did, and then recovered the original data. Not something I am very keen on, but that's the way people are doing things.